# call a value from dropdown list to update query

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to make a page with drop down list, i want the user to add which cinema name he want and send it via mysql query to the database.

now, this is what i did to get the dropdown list from the database (this part is working)

```
<select name="cinema_id" id="cinemaid">
    <?php
    require('../classes/cinema_class.php');
    $cinemas = cinema::get_cinemas_name(); 
$cinema_id = $cinema['cinema_id'];
$cinema_name = $cinema['cinema_name'];

    foreach($cinemas as $cinema)
    {
        $selected = '';
        if( $cinema['cinema_id'] == $_GET['cinema_id'])
        {
            $selected = 'select="selected"';
        }

        echo "<option {$selected} >
            {$cinema['cinema_name']}
            </option>";
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

and this is the mysql query to update

```
<?php
$theaterid=$_POST['theaterid'];
$theatername=$_POST['theatername'];
$cinemaid=$_POST['cinemaid'];
if(empty($theatername)){  
echo  "Theater Name is a must";
}
else{
$update_movie=mysql_query("UPDATE `memoire`.`theater` 
            SET `theater_name`= '$theatername',`cinema_id`= '$cinemaid' //the $theatername is working, i think the $cinemaid is wrong
            WHERE `theater_id`='$theaterid'");
if($update_movie)
{ echo "Add Succesfull";}
else
{ echo "error in registration".mysql_error(); }
}?>
```

i think the problem is what to do to call the value in the dropdown list and send it to the update

By the way, the page print:
error in registrationCannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`memoire`.`theater`, CONSTRAINT `theater_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`cinema_id`) REFERENCES `cinema` (`cinema_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Answer (score 0):

I think the cinema_id is the current cinema_name. Change this line:

```
echo "<option {$selected} >
```

to

```
echo "<option {$selected} value='{$cinema[cinema_id]}' >
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first snippet, inside of your , you need to have a value attribute.

```
echo "<option value='{$cinema['cinema_id']}' {$selected} >
            {$cinema['cinema_name']}
            </option>";
```

That will at least post the correct data to the server. In the second snippet, you are referencing the html select's id, not the name. You should be using the name.

```
$cinemaid=$_POST['cinema_id']; // notice the underscore
```

That should give you correct value on the server, once posted.

As a side note, your scripts are open to [SQL Injection](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDQQFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection&ei=mcFyUa7cI4SIqwHx6IGwCw&usg=AFQjCNGcGZNbIk2jM8itxItHrCja7eJ0PQ&sig2=J8dL99OWE9_hf_mUzz_8Wg&bvm=bv.45512109,d.aWM) and [Cross-Site Scripting](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDEQFjAA&url=https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting&ei=uMFyUYCTEcfGrQHl44Bg&usg=AFQjCNF8gcMuXHACArbxvQ0vCgcPHMWSlg&sig2=z81Xtx350jhz-kTT28kSnA&bvm=bv.45512109,d.aWM). You may want to take a look at those.

Comment: did u see the error??

error in registrationCannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (memoire.theater, CONSTRAINT theater_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (cinema_id) REFERENCES cinema (cinema_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

i think smth is wrong inside the database maybe??

Comment: Nothing is wrong inside of your database. The cinema obviously exists in the database, otherwise it wouldn't be in your dropdown list. So referencing it should be fine.

The problem is with your data handling. You must be passing the wrong variables in to the SQL query. Before you run the query, print it out and make sure your $cinemaid is what you think it is. If it's not a number, that's your problem.

Answer (score 0):

i think now i can ask a better question.
in my database i need to add the cinema_id.
the dropdown list give me the cinema_name...so i need the user to select cinema_name BUT i need to add the cinema_id of it to the update query

thank you

Answer (score 0):

This issue has nothing to do with your code snippet above but rather how your have set up your foreign keys in your database.  Can you post the structure of the table you reference above as well as the cinema table pointing out how you have set up your referential keys?